# How to set the number of sample in KFold validation?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm having a dataframework of 60k records labelled as 0 or 1. To make some test I would like to make two different cross validation, the 1st using 20k records and the 2nd using 40k records.

To do so I used the n_sample parameter in make_classification:

```
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=40000)
```

However I'm having this warning:

```
UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
```

And my output is:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.50      1.00      0.67     20019
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00     19981

    accuracy                           0.50     40000
   macro avg       0.25      0.50      0.33     40000
weighted avg       0.25      0.50      0.33     40000
```

Whit `0.00` value for P,R and F1.

Here a snapshot of my code

```
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=40000)

start = time()

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf',
              C=3,
              gamma=3,
              )

print("K-Folds scores:")

originalclass = []
predictedclass = []


def classification_report_with_accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred):
    originalclass.extend(y_true)
    predictedclass.extend(y_pred)
    return accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)  # return accuracy score


inner_cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)
outer_cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)


# Nested CV with parameter optimization
nested_score = cross_val_score(clf, X=X, y=y, cv=outer_cv, 
                               scoring=make_scorer(classification_report_with_accuracy_score))

# Average values in classification report for all folds in a K-fold Cross-validation  
print(classification_report(originalclass, predictedclass))
print("10 folds processing seconds: {}".format(time() - start))
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What exatcly is the problem? The error message you showed? This comes from the fact that your model only predicts class 0 and never class 1. Or that you don't know how to implement your two stage cross-validation?

Comment: @Tinu thanks for your comment. This is clear. But, why using the ```X, y = make_classification(n_samples=60000)``` the accuracy is 0.50 and without is 0.87. Since the whole df is 60k I would expect 0.87 as value also by using the n_sample=60000. Or not?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue with `resample`

```
from sklearn.utilis import resample

  ...

X, y = resample (X, y, n_samples=40000, replace=False, stratify=y)
```